# Pass data between multiple NodeJS servers

Tags: node.js

I am still pretty new to NodeJS and want to know if I am looking at this in the wrong way.

Background:
I am making an app that runs once a week, generates a report, and then emails that out to a list of recipients. My initial reason for using Node was because I have an existing front end already built using angular and I wanted to be able to reuse code in order to simplify maintenance. My main idea was to have 4+ individual node apps running in parallel on our server.

The first app would use node-cron in order to run every Sunday. This would check the database for all scheduled tasks and retrieve the stored parameters for the reports it is running.

The next app is a simple queue that would store the scheduled tasks and pass them to the worker tasks.

The actual pdf generation would be somewhat CPU intensive, so this would be a cluster of n apps that would retrieve and run individual reports from the queue.

When done making the pdf, they would pass to a final email app that would send the file out.

My main concerns are communication between apps. At the moment I am setting up the 3 lower levels (ie. all but the scheduler) on separate ports with express, and opening http requests to them when needed. Is there a better way to handle this? Would the basic 'net' work better than the 'http' package? Is Express even necessary for something like this, or would I be better off running everything as a basic http/net server? So far the only real use I've made of Express is to specifically listen to a path for put requests and to parse the incoming json. I was led to asking here because in tracking logs so far I see every so often the http request is reset, which doesn't appear to affect the data received on the child process, but I still like to avoid errors in my coding.

Answer (score 1):

I think that his kind of decoupling could leverage some sort of stateful priority queue with features like retry on failure, clustering, ...

I've used Kue.js in the past with great sucess, it's redis backed and has nice documentation and interface http://automattic.github.io/kue/

Comment: Kue is a good solution but if you want something more robust take a look at: https://www.rabbitmq.com